# How to Access Web Elements in Nested HTML Tags Using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a website that generates a report within an iframe, and the website's HTML structure is laid out to look like the following:

```html
<html> <!-- a -->
  <body>
    .
    . (C)
    .
    <iframe>
      <html> <!-- b -->
        <body>
        .
        . (D)
        .
        </body>
      </html>
    </iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

I am wondering how I can access elements in the body containing "(D)" from above. So far I have tried using xpath, but if I copy the xpath from an element in (D) in begins from html tag b, so when the program starts searching from html tag a, it finds nothing. I tested to see if the  has any child web elements, and it has 0. Attempts to search for elements in (D) by ID have also also resulted in NoSuchElementException. Not a time problem because I am using WebDriverWait for 120 seconds to make sure everything on page has loaded. Thank you for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it's in an iframe you need to use switchTo to grab the DOM of the frame.
See more here: https://www.techbeamers.com/switch-between-iframes-selenium-python/ or https://www.guru99.com/handling-iframes-selenium.html

```
driver.switch_to.iframe(self,frame reference)
```

where reference is:

By using the tag name ( in this case ‘iframe’)

By using the Id of IFrame

By using the name of IFrame